# change a folder permission in root directory

Tags: permissions, chmod

I want to change a folder permission in root directory ( /backup like /home) when I tried

```
chmod 755 /backup
```

it changes for a day and after a day its permission changes back. how can I change it forever?

---

I tested it in mount and unmounted state but It's not solved

---

```
drw------- 6 user1 nobody 102 Jan 8 03:10 /backup
```

I move the users to `/backup` from `/home`.

Comment: Does that happen on every reboot as well? Are you using Linux with systemd?

Comment: It's unclear what Unix you are using and what the permissions on the directory are reverted back to. It would also be helpful to know the ownership of the directory (`ls -dl /backup` would show all of this). What does "`/backup` like `/home`" mean? Did you run the command that you show as the root user?

Comment: Instead of adding clarifications in _answers_, consider [edit]ing your question.